# One Way To Match Array of String and List of String

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, linq

I am trying to match list of string and array string using **foreach** loop but in my case, it seems I require to iterate a lot to match corresponding values. I've the following:

```
string[] splitValues = item.ValuesWithComma.Split(',');
```

So it has indexes and in the same way, the list of string will have the equal indexes. So is it possible to match those directly with indexes as follows to avoid loops:

```
splitValues == item.lstOfValues;
```

Right now, I am iterating every time to match and it seems really inappropriate.

```
foreach (var item in lstOfValues)
{
   foreach (var item2 in splitValues )
   {
      //Condition goes here 
   }
}
```

**N.B**: Both the types may have equal no. of indexes and if unmatched, it'll be skipped. Match means here, the types may have equal no. of values.

Comment: Can you define match? what do you want it to do give back a true or false, or a list or... ?

Comment: Just true or false. If match found, true otherwise vice-versa @TheGeneral.

Comment: So you want to compare each item? Or want to check whether all items are matching?i mean return true if all matching else false

Comment: All items are same or matching @vivek nuna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bool equal = ls1.SequenceEqual(ls2);`, It will match the lists sequentially as well.

Comment: OK but will it work for these type matching **string[] splitValues** with **List<string> str** @vivek nuna?

Comment: As you described in the question you have string only. It will also work for int[] splitValues with List<int> str